# What is the longest passenger flight (with a flight number) in the world?

Tags: air-travel, routes, long-haul, statistics, factoids

For example, JQ151 from Sydney to Christchurch is around 3 hours.  NZ1 however, is about another 7 to Hong Kong.

Will need a regular flight number to verify.

Definition is longest in terms of flight time / distance (they should be linked, logically?).

Comment: Do you mean longest non-stop flight or is that including stopovers? What about "technical breaks" like fuel stopovers?

Comment: as long as it's the same flight number, that's fine.  I was going to say longest trip, but you could be a weasel and hop to every state in the US before going to the UK, for example :P

Comment: Flight time and distance are related by not directly proportional. Plane speeds vary, and the very regular jet stream air currents can make a huge difference in average flight times.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5064/101

Comment: I don't have access to look it up right now, but I believe JFK-JNB is a single flight number, with a tech stop in Dakkar. 18 or 20 hours if memory serves.

Comment: "Longest" flights are always going to include crossing the equator. Once you have to do that, you can't take advantage of a near-polar route.

Comment: Sounds like trivia.

Comment: Related only: I've read that flight with the longest time to the closest airstrip in the case of an emergency is NZ-South America.

Comment: Longest flight currently is Saudia airlines flight (JED-LAX).

Comment: @MeNoTalk not [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-stop_flight#Longest_flights), it's 5th.

Comment: As of 2016/10/16, the longest non-stop is now Air India's Delhi to San Francisco route at 15,100 km.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The longest **non-stop** (by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Airlines_Flight_21) source) flight is Newark to Singapore on Singapore Airlines flight SQ21 which is and 18 hour 50 minute flight of some 15,345km.

However for **single flight number, allowing stopover**, things are hard to research. Not many websites list tables of distances by flight number. So I resorted to thinking of a route and then looking on the airline websites to see if it was one flight number or split over two flight numbers.

I suspect the longest route that could be a single flight number and have a stopover would be Northern Europe to Australia. So I searched on several airlines for flights. I found a few contenders (but no definitive answers):

- NZ1 and NZ38, both on Air New Zealand fly London to Auckland with a stop in Hong Kong in 26 hours and 40 minutes. A distance of 18,463 km.
- QF320 on Qantas and BA15 on British Airways fly London to Sydney with a stopover in Singapore. They both take 22 hours and 50 minutes.
- QF1 on Qantas goes from Sydney to London, again stopping in Singapore and is 23 hours and 25 minutes.

Comment: I've done that NZ1/38 flight.  The worst part is finally getting to AKL, and then still having to fly to CHC!

Comment: not that far behind, Paris-Papeete by Air France AF076/077 takes respectively 22h30 and 20h55 with a stop in LA. I could not find the distance though.

Comment: There is a flight from a French colony (Nouvelle Calédonie, I think) in the South Pacific to Paris via Réunion. I have no idea on any details (flight number, distance, time) but it might be a candidate. It basically goes west across Australia, lands in Réunion to pick up passengers (this is where I got on) and then flies north west over the Horn of Africa to Paris.

Comment: [CNN's Richard Quest](https://www.cnn.com/videos/aviation/2017/03/09/business-traveller-long-haul-a.cnn/video/playlists/intl-business-traveller/) claims that, as of March 2017, the longest non-stop flight is Qatar's QR921 from Auckland to Doha at 17.5 hours and 14,550km.

Answer (score 13):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-stop_flight#Currently_scheduled_.28top_30.2C_by_distance.29):

> [Newark](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/newark-liberty.html) - [Singapore](http://www.changiairport.com/) ([Singapore Airlines](http://www.singaporeair.com))
>     flight number: **SQ 21**,
>     15,345km (9,535 miles, 8,285 nautical miles)
>     from 18 hr 40 min to 18 hr 50 min,
>     aircraft: [Airbus A340-500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A340#A340-500),
>     first flight - [29 June 2004](http://www.airways.ch/files/2004/0604/010/sia345.htm)

Second place:

> [Los Angeles](http://www.lawa.org/welcomeLAX.aspx) - [Singapore](http://www.changiairport.com/) ([Singapore Airlines](http://www.singaporeair.com))
>     flight number: **SQ 37**,
>     14,114km (8,770 miles, 7,621 nautical miles)
>     from 17 hr 20 min to 18 hr 05 min,
>     aircraft: [Airbus A340-500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A340#A340-500),
>     first flight - [3 February 2004](http://toolkit.bootsnall.com/transportation-travel-guide/air-travel-guide/ask-the-pilot-collection/airline-reviews/singapore-airlines-longest-flight.html)

Third place (surprisingly only by distance, but not by time)

> [Sydney](http://www.sydneyairport.com.au/) - [Dallas](http://www.dfwairport.com/) ([Qantas](http://www.qantas.com.au/))
>     flight number: **QF 7**,
>     13,804km (8,578 miles, 7,454 nautical miles)
>     15 hr 25 min,
>     aircraft: [Boeing 747-400](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747-400),
>     first flight - [16 May 2011](http://airlineroute.net/2011/01/14/qf-sfodfw-s11/)

Third place by time:

> [Los Angeles](http://www.lawa.org/welcomeLAX.aspx) - [Bangkok](http://www.suvarnabhumiairport.com/index_en.php) ([Thai Airways International](http://www.thaiairways.com/))
>     flight number: **TG 795**,
>     13,309km (8,270 miles, 7,186 nautical miles)
>     17 hr 20 min,
>     aircraft: [Airbus A340-500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A340#A340-500),
>     first flight - 28 September 2006

Comment: So I think you should try out the flight from Newark to LA via Singapore

Comment: SQ21 and SQ37 are special in that they are business class only planes in order to reduce weight and allow them to cover such a long distance.  QF7 Sydney to Dallas is non-stop, but the return QF8 can only make it as far as Brisbane, where it has to stop for fuel.

Comment: As far as I know, the time difference between QF7 and TG795 is due to more favorable prevailing winds in the case of QF7.

Answer (score 11):

The longest flight by flight number (including stops) would be [Korean Air's flight 062](http://planefinder.net/data/flights/KE62) from Guarulhos Gov Andre Franco Montouro (GRU) in Sao Paulo, Brazil to Incheon Intl (ICN) in South Korea via Los Angeles International (LAX). It is 28 hours and 35 minutes.

Answer (score 10):

Since the [two answers so far will no longer be valid soon](http://www.20min.ch/finance/dossier/luftverkehr/story/Der-laengste-Flug-der-Welt-ist-am-Ende-27957390), I thought it is time to add a new answer:

Singapore Airlines is cancelling their nonstop flights from Newark to Singapore and from Los Angeles to Singapore. So the longest flight will be Sydney - Dallas by Qantas (QF7).

Answer (score 10):

According to [this CNN article](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/coronavirus-worlds-longest-flight/index.html), the record has been broken because of the COVID-19 outbreak:

> On March 14, French airline Air Tahiti Nui flew the longest ever scheduled passenger flight by distance -- transiting 9,765 miles across the world from Papeete, in Tahiti, French Polynesia, to Paris' Charles de Gaulle airport.
>
> This one off milestone was a direct consequence of the coronavirus-induced US travel restrictions.
>
> This route usually involves a scheduled stopover at Los Angeles International Airport (LAX). But when an airplane stops over in the US, all passengers must alight the aircraft and proceed through US Customs and Border Protection before they're allowed to advance on with the next leg of their journey.
>
> Current restrictions rendered this part of the journey untenable, so instead, flight TN064 just carried straight on, departing at 3 a.m. local time from Papeete airport and arriving in Paris at 6:30 a.m. local time on March 15.

This *is* a scheduled flight, but a one time deviation from the schedule (though the situation may continue to be like this in the near future).

Comment: For those who are curious, [here's the FlightAware track](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/THT64/history/20200315/1300Z/NTAA/LFPG).

Comment: Further trivia: it's technically a domestic flight.

Answer (score 7):

Air India Flight 173 from New Delhi to San Francisco is the world's longest flight. It covers over 15,000 km (9,300 miles) en route, over the Pacific Ocean in about 15 hours.

This is from [Flightaware](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/AIC173):

[image]
<sub>(source: [quoracdn.net](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-c457c24daaf18ab541576db46067f554-c?convert_to_webp=true))</sub>

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-stop_flight) has now been updated as well.

> Since 15 October 2016, Air India Flight 173 from New Delhi to San Francisco started flying over the Pacific Ocean. Tailwinds over the Pacific Ocean helped in reducing the flight time by 2 hours, despite increasing the total distance by 1,100 km. This also made AI 173 the world's longest flight by actual distance flown, with total distance traveled being over 15,100 km (9400 miles).The return flight AI 174 however still flies over the Atlantic Ocean, to take advantage of tailwinds in that direction. Air India therefore advertised this route as around the world flight, as it departs over Pacific and returns over Atlantic.

Some other interesting articles and videos on AI 173:

1. [Air India taking advantage of tailwinds](https://www.flightradar24.com/blog/air-india-taking-advantage-of-tailwinds/)
2. [Air India now operates the world's longest routing (sort of)](https://onemileatatime.com/air-india-longest-flight/)
3. [Official statement by Air India captain Rajneesh Sharma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBJFfFFluxM)

Comment: That is really interesting! Another fresh flight, Air Canada 73, between Vancouver - New Delhi http://flightaware.com/live/flight/ACA73 which is a more modest 6928 miles seems to fly over the North Pole and Vancouver - San Francisco is just 795 miles so that route would be 7723 miles.

Comment: Air India is also starting Bangalore-San Francisco which definitely has to be more kms than DEL-SFO assuming it also flies over the Pacific. Flight AI175 starts 11th Jan.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an update for 2016:

> Early on 3 March, Emirates flight 449 made history when it touched down in Dubai from Auckland. The Airbus A380 covered an estimated 9,000 miles between New Zealand’s largest city and the airline's hub, making it the current longest non-stop scheduled commercial flight by a distance.

[The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/emirates-flight-449-worlds-longest-flight-between-auckland-and-dubai-could-trigger-fares-war-a6909976.html)

Here is what we can look forward to in the coming years:

> Qatar Airways Flight 921 from Auckland to Doha, which will be the longest flight in the world, will be flown with a Boeing 777-200LR when it starts 2 February 2017, overtaking Emirates' spot with their Auckland-Dubai flight.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-stop_flight)
>
> Singapore Airlines revealed plans last year to bring back its Singapore-New Jersey service in 2018. The flight will apparently cover some 15,300km (9,500 miles) in 19 hours.

Comment: A single flight number is not necessarily a single leg. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/16042/4188 this answer.