# Starting from any commercial airport, can I reach any other commercial airport in the world with just scheduled passenger flights?

Tags: air-travel, factoids, routes

A commercial airport being any airport that has regular scheduled passenger flights.

The mathematics of [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81783/what-commercial-flight-route-requires-the-most-stops-layovers-from-a-to-b) got me thinking: is the network of scheduled flights a connected graph?

That is, is there a pair (or triplet or even larger set) of airports such that they only have scheduled flights with each other?  Or can you get from any airport to any other?

Ignore vagaries like cargo and general aviation. I'm looking for two airports that I can shuttle between, but would have to drive (or sail) to get to one or the other of them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99710/discussion-on-question-by-malvolio-starting-from-any-commercial-airport-can-i-r).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one such pair of airports:

[Westerly State Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westerly_State_Airport) (Rhode Island) and [Block Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Island_State_Airport) (Rhode Island)

There are [frequent scheduled flights](http://www.block-island.com/) between the two airports, and neither seems to offer scheduled flights anywhere else at this time.

Comment: Wouldn't the New York Seaplane Base count?

Comment: @JonathanReez There are no flights to the New York Seaplane Base base now. There may have been some during the summer.

Comment: still, those are scheduled flights, even if they are seasonal

Comment: Specifically, it looks like [Tropic Ocean Airways](https://flytropic.com/press/tropic-ocean-airways-announce-new-york-seaplane-service-new-york-travel-show) operated at least some weekend flights to Block Island during this past summer, but they've since [gone down to Florida](https://flytropic.com/scheduled-flights). There are no flights scheduled from New York to Block Island at this time. Maybe they'll come back next summer, but they don't have a schedule, won't let you book such a flight, and packed up and moved their operation 1,000 miles south, so I don't think they count right now.

Comment: That's a good one, how did you find it?  The sea-plane thing may disqualify it (if I can find another example).

Comment: @Malvolio Mostly searching for some variants of "island shuttle flights," since I figured those would have a better chance of quickly satisfying the criteria.

Answer (score 21):

The Nouvelle Calédonie domestic network, operated by [Air Calédonie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Cal%C3%A9donie) and [Air Loyauté](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Loyaut%C3%A9) with a hub on the [Nouméa Magenta Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noum%C3%A9a_Magenta_Airport) near downtown Nouméa, and serving a dozen or so smaller airfield, in Nouvelle Calédonie or nearby islands does qualify.

[image: https://www.aeroports.cci.nc/fr/magenta/destinations]

The [Magenta airport page](https://www.aeroports.cci.nc/en/magenta/vols/recherche?way=departures) lists more than 20 departures for next friday (11/10/2019), most of them using  [ATR 72](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/f-ozno) so it is not just a glorified general aviation network.

Links to global scheduled flight "connected graph" (i.e. flights to other french territories and to foreign countries) are scheduled from [La Tontouta Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Tontouta_International_Airport), 50 km away by [Aircalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircalin) and other airlines. Local ones are not allowed to land on La Tontouta Airport.

[image: https://www.aeroports.cci.nc/fr/tontouta/vols/recherche]

Both maps are from the [CCI-CN website](https://www.aeroports.cci.nc/en/magenta)

Answer (score 7):

Arkhangelsk has two airports: Talagi, which serves Moscow & St. Petersburg, etc, and Vas'kovo, which serves towns and villages within the region. It also does helicopters. As with already existing answer, there's 20 km between these two.

Also, Reykjavik airport (the small one) mostly serves airstrips in Iceland, which makes it unconnected. Or maybe occassionally connected via e.g. Greenland.

I think this is a very popular pattern out there.

Comment: From Reykjavik you can fly to Nuuk and then to Kangerlussuaq and then to Copenhagen, so it doesn't qualify

Comment: Does not qualify this year, maybe year ago or next year it would.
Actually, Vas'kovo will only qualify in winter half of year, too, because in the summer you can do Vas'kovo - Solovki - Talagi - Moscow, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Like some other users, I found this question via another one that has been closed already, today.
There are three to four [planes](http://www.flughafen-helgoland.de/flugplan_helgoland_heide-buesum.html) daily from German island Helgoland to Heide/Büsum. Flightradar dot com does not list this service, but I believe it still qualifies as a `scheduled service`. However, there's no commercial service leaving HEI/EDXB.