# Is there anywhere a scheduled air service between two airports without connections to the wider world?

Tags: air-travel

Mostly, if an airport, however minor, has scheduled service, it will be to another airport with more services and so one can connect through to any airport in the world. E.g. one can fly from [ISC - Isles of Scilly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Mary%27s_Airport,_Isles_of_Scilly) to [NQY - Newquay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newquay_Airport) to LHR to anywhere else.

But is there a pair or set of airports where this doesn't hold, creating an "island" of unconnected air transport?

(Fixed wing or I guess helicopter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting from any commercial airport, can I reach any other commercial airport in the world with just scheduled passenger flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81832/starting-from-any-commercial-airport-can-i-reach-any-other-commercial-airport-i) (which was closed for being off-topic.)